# Facebook graph API & PHP SDK questions

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any limit to access graph API or php sdk in facebook (like XXX no. of hits allowed per day/hour)

Comment: If there is, I have not seen it mentioned anywhere. There are some huge applications out there. I doubt there is a limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880591/facebook-graph-api-search

Answer (score 2):

See Policies, Features and Functionality point five:

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

" If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us by creating a confidential bug report with the "threshold policy" tag as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day)."

100 million API calls a day is hard to hit eh? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a token from the current logged in user, the limit was 600 requests/minute a few months ago, haven't checked since. If you are using an application token, I haven't seen any limits, at least ones that can be tested by a mid-range server.